# How to authenticate a pod with its service account token on a OIDC server

Tags: kubernetes, authentication

I have a k8s cluster, on this cluster I have a service AA and a service BB. On this same cluster I have a keycloak instance running. AA's pods has a service account token. BB has a service and listens in HTTP, it has a OpenID middleware to verify the authentication configured with keycloak.

I want that AA makes requests on BB authenticated with a keycloak token, and I would like that AA gets the keycloak token with its service account token without having to configure long lived secrets.
Is it even possible ? What's the alternatives: connect directly BB with the service token review API of k8s, long secrets are the only way